# Spring-XD does not read logback.xml

Tags: java, spring, logback, spring-xd

I am trying to run a job in Spring-XD, located under the following path:

```
/spring-xd/xd/modules/job/MyJobName (I'll call this path MyJobName below)
```

My jar, located under `MyJobName/lib`, contains in its root path the file logback.xml. Unfortunately, Spring-XD seems to be completely ignoring that file. When I run the job through my IDE (IntelliJ), the logging works fine, but when I run it using Spring-XD it completely ignores my SiftingAppender.

Here is what my logback.xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%5p %-25logger{25} %m %n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="SIFT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
        <discriminator>
            <key>publication.run.id</key>
            <defaultValue>unknown</defaultValue>
        </discriminator>
        <sift>
            <appender name="FILE-${publication.run.id}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
                <file>/data/${publication.run.id}/logs/process.log</file>
                <append>true</append>
                <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                    <pattern>%5p %-25logger{25} %m %n</pattern>
                </layout>
            </appender>
        </sift>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.bitwiseor">
        <level value="INFO" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework">
        <level value="INFO" />
    </logger>

    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="SIFT" />
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

I want to put this logback.xml file under /spring-xd/xd/config, or under another configuration folder, but nothing I try works. I tried looking through the Spring-XD docs, but found nothing.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: could you add some information about your application.properties? and how you start your job? it could be, that the runtime environment doesn't know, the location of your logback.xml

Comment: also make sure, that logback is in your class path, when you start your job

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to put Logback **directly in the classpath**. See [here](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#auto_configuration):

> Logback can be configured either programmatically or with a configuration script expressed in XML or Groovy format. By the way, existing log4j users can convert their log4j.properties files to logback.xml using our PropertiesTranslator web-application.
>
> Let us begin by discussing the initialization steps that logback follows to try to configure itself:
>
> - Logback tries to find a file called logback.groovy in the classpath.
> - If no such file is found, logback tries to find a file called logback-test.xml in the classpath.
> - If no such file is found, it checks for the file logback.xml in the classpath.
> - If no such file is found, and the executing JVM has the ServiceLoader (JDK 6 and above) the ServiceLoader will be used to resolve an implementation of com.qos.logback.classic.spi.Configurator. The first implementation found will be used. See ServiceLoader documentation for more details.
> - If none of the above succeeds, logback configures itself automatically using the BasicConfigurator which will cause logging output to be directed to the console.

It sounds to me like your configuration file is **not in the classpath**. Generally the config directory is not in the classpath by default in most frameworks, in many cases it's `/config/<files>` that are in the class path, and you have to specify them with `/config/name` when loading them with the `ClassLoader`. However, Logback doesn't do that, so if you want to store the files in the `config` directory, you have to load them manually.

Essentially, you can tell [`JoranConfigurator`](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/joran/JoranConfigurator.html) to load the file from a custom location in your classpath, handle the errors, and so forth to make sure you've found your file. See [here for more details.](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#joranDirectly)

Here is how I load my Logback config, you can probably adapt this to your system. In this case `resource` is the path within your classpath to wherever you've decided to put your `logback.xml` file. In this case it would probably be `/spring-xd/xd/config/logback.xml`.

```
public class LogbackConfigurator {
    private static final Logger LOG =
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogbackConfigurator.class);
    
    public static boolean configure(String resource) throws JoranException {
        final InputStream configInputStream = LogbackConfigurator.class.getResourceAsStream(resource);
        final LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
        
        JoranConfigurator configurator = new JoranConfigurator();
        configurator.setContext(loggerContext);
        //  the context was probably already configured by default configuration rules
        loggerContext.reset();
        
        if(configInputStream != null) {
            try {
                configurator.doConfigure(configInputStream);
            } catch (JoranException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            StatusPrinter.printInCaseOfErrorsOrWarnings(loggerContext);
            return true;
        } else {
            LOG.error("Unable to find logback file: {}", resource);
            StatusPrinter.printInCaseOfErrorsOrWarnings(loggerContext);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Typically, this method would be called as one of the first lines in `main` with something like:

```
LogbackConfigurator.configure(path);
```

Once this class has been run, your logback should be configured as if the system had been able to find the configuration file normally. Note that you can also use [`-Dproperty=value`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#BABDJJFI) and `System.getProperties().get(keyname)` to specify an alternate location for the path to the logback file dynamically if you don't want to hardcode the location into your system.

You can also configure the location to be injected in your Spring configuration, but I personally don't recommend that as you would normally like logging to be configured *before* injection occurs, so that if any logging events occur during injection, they will be logged appropriately.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like your **logback** configuration is having some minor issues.

Try putting the below configuration into your application classpath; should resolve the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%5p %-25logger{25} %m %n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="SIFT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
        <discriminator>
            <key>publication.run.id</key>
            <defaultValue>unknown</defaultValue>
        </discriminator>
        <sift>
            <appender name="FILE-${publication.run.id}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
                <file>/data/${publication.run.id}/logs/process.log</file>
                <append>true</append>
                <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                    <pattern>%5p %-25logger{25} %m %n</pattern>
                </layout>
            </appender>
        </sift>
    </appender>
    <logger name="com.bitwiseor" level="INFO" />
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO" />
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="SIFT" />
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

**Note** below part is changed according to the logback configuration reference:

```
<logger name="com.bitwiseor" level="INFO" />
<logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO" />
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="SIFT" />
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</root>
```